# How to increase vertical size of CSS image element without changing anything else

Tags: html, css

I have a tag image built using CSS I've found around the web (because I'm not a CSS expert and am kind of flailing about). I wanted to make the tag a little bit more "chunky" and have gotten close to perfect. You'll notice the background for the tag (the darker red) does not line up with the bottom corner of the diamond shape with the hole. If I just increase the size it will then cause other mis-alignment in places. Here is my current image:

[image: tag image]

The desired result should look like this:

[image]

Here is my CSS:

```
.tags {
  a {
    color: #fff;
    &:visited {
      color: #fff;
    }
    &:hover {
      color: #fff;
      background-color: #e94016;
    }
  }
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  position: relative;
  content: "";
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 10px 25px 10px 15px;
  padding: 3px 28px 3px 20px;
  border: none;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  font: normal 14px/16px "Antic", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  background: #b23111;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 0 0 #e94016 , 2px 6px 0 1px #e94016 ;
  box-shadow: 0 6px 0 0 #e94016 , 2px 6px 0 1px #e94016 ;
}

.tags::before {
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 19px;
  height: 19px;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 2px;
  right: -4px;
  border: none;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font: normal 0/normal Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
  -o-text-overflow: clip;
  text-overflow: clip;
  background: #b23111;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 0 0 #e94016 ;
  box-shadow: 0 6px 0 0 #e94016 ;
  text-shadow: none;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(1deg) rotateZ(-45deg)   ;
  transform: rotateY(1deg) rotateZ(-45deg)   ;
}

.tags::after {
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 7px;
  right: 2px;
  border: none;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font: normal medium/normal Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
  -o-text-overflow: clip;
  text-overflow: clip;
  background: #fcfcfc;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 0 0 #e94016 inset;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 0 0 #e94016 inset;
  text-shadow: none;
}
```

html is:

```
<li class="tags"><a href="#" data-original-title="" title="">9500XL,</a></li>
```

Comment: My guess is to increase the vertical size of the main rectangle, move it down a bit with regard to the text, and make the lighter border that much thinner to compensate. Problem is I have no idea where to begin to do that!

Comment: can you provide your html part

Comment: I added it, but not sure if that is what you are referring to. I am using Rails with Bootstrap 3.2 but I think the CSS above is stand alone from that since I added it. Shouldn't this be entirely determined by CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `a:before` for the below shadow.

***Stack Snippet***

```css
.tags a {
  color: #fff;
}

.tags a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #e94016;
}

.tags {
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  position: relative;
  content: "";
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 10px 25px 10px 15px;
  padding: 3px 28px 3px 20px;
  border: none;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  font: normal 14px/16px "Antic", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  background: #b23111;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 0 0 #e94016;
  box-shadow: 0 6px 0 0 #e94016;
}

.tags::before {
  display: inline-block;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: 2px;
  right: -4px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #b23211;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.tags a::before {
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 7px;
  right: 2px;
  border: none;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font: normal medium/normal Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  -o-text-overflow: clip;
  text-overflow: clip;
  background: #fcfcfc;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 0 0 #e94016 inset;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 0 0 #e94016 inset;
  text-shadow: none;
}

.tags::after {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: 8px;
  right: -4px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #e94017;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<li class="tags"><a href="#" data-original-title="" title="">9500XL,</a></li>
```

Comment: It works great in the SO snippet so I'm a believer, but I copy and replace my code with yours and I the lighter color shadow is missing the diamond end on the right. I'll have to figure out what's wrong on my end, something might be overriding it. Thanks for the correct answer!

Comment: For some reason the `a::before` is not drawing in my browser. I tried all the browsers so it's something in the rest of my CSS (some Bootstrap, some custom) that is interfering. This is why I'm a backend dev! LOL!

Comment: @Beartech Can you share the url where I can find the issue?

Comment: I don't have it online yet. No worries, I'm sure the issue is with a lot of other code that is probably interfering. I'm using this in Rails and one of the gems has a management panel that clobbers a bunch of CSS because of poor design on its part. I have a friend who is an HTML/CSS wiz who should be able to look over the code on my laptop to help figure it out. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: AHA! it has something to do with `z-index: -1;`? If I change it to `z-index: 0;` it will show up, but on top of the dark part of the rectangle. So something it the z-axis is making it fall behind and disappear.

Comment: It appears as if I'm trying to place the `a::before` between the `.tags` background and box shadow?

Comment: @Beartech Try to set `z-index:0` to anchor tag and then `-1` to `:before`. I think it will work.

Comment: Sadly no change. ARGH!!! thought I was on to something. But is it even possible to put it between the background and box shadow of the element? Maybe I just need to break it up more and rebuild the layers from bottom to top so I know what's going on.